# Creating a firebase notification with the use of Yii2 as a backend

Tags: android, firebase, yii2, firebase-notifications

I'm creating a basic Guest Service Request system with the use of Yii2 which has a function of when there's a new request that was inputted to the system the employee phone will be notified.

How do I create a firebase notification in Android, I don't really have any ideas but I do have some basic knowledge when it comes to Android developing.

Answer (score 2):

Some basic steps:

1. Add the [Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) in your Android application.
2. Get the authorization key.
3. Get the registration token for the client app instance.
4. Send the registration token to the server.
5. Send HTTP request in Yii anytime you want to send the notification:

   ```
   https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
   Content-Type:application/json
   Authorization:key=Your_Authorization_Key
   {
       "registration_ids": ["registration_token"],
       "data": {
           "message": "This is a Firebase Message!",
       }
   }
   ```
6. [Receive notification in Android app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive).